# Characterization of orthogonality in an inner product space.

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

How can I show the following assertion

> In an inner product space, $x\perp y$ if and only if $\|x+\alpha y\|\ge \|x\|$ for all scalars $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\langle x+\alpha y,x+\alpha y\rangle\geq\langle x,x\rangle
$$
After rearranging,
$$
\alpha\langle x,y\rangle+\bar \alpha\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}\geq-|\alpha|^2\langle y,y\rangle.
$$
Choosing $\alpha=-\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}/n$, we get
$$
-(1/n)2|\langle x,y\rangle|^2\geq-(1/n^2)|\langle x,y\rangle|^2\|y\|^2.
$$
Multiply by $-n$ and take the limit $n\rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Does this work when $\alpha\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: Edited it to apply for spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ too.